# Does a foreign key always refer to a primary key?

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, data-modeling

I'm a bit confused about this. Must a foreign key always reference a primaryy key? What if there's two foreign key on the same table that refer to the same primary key?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give us an example of a table where you would actually need this?

Comment: An SQL FK references a PK or UNIQUE. It tells the DBMS that non-null subrows for the FK must be subrows in the referenced table. When that is so & it is not implied by previous declarations, declare it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "What if there's two foreign key on the same table that refer to the same primary key?
>   "

Any number of child tables can reference a parent table. There are certain situations in which it is possible for a child table to have more than one foreign key on the same parent.

For instance, any form of sporting contest has opponents of the same type - player, team, etc. So a match will have two instances  of that entity, hance the child table will have two columns with foreign keys referencing the same primary key.

```
create table player (
    player_id number not null primary key
    , name varchar2(30) not null unique
);
create table match (
    match_id number not null primary key
    , player_1 number not null 
    , player_2 number not null 
    , match_played date not null
    , result varchar2(10)
    , constraint match_player1_fk foreign key (player_1) references player
    , constraint match_player2_fk foreign key (player_2) references player
);
```

A foreign key can reference a unique constraint rather than a primary key. However this is not standard practice. It is the convention to use unique keys to enforce candidate keys - business keys - and these are not always suitable for use as foreign keys.

For instance in my example, `PLAYER.NAME` is a unique key: every player must have a distinct name. However, it would not be appropriate to use `NAME` as the foreign key on `MATCH` because people can change their name. It is more convenient to use the synthetic primary key, `PLAYER_ID` because that will not change over the lifetime of the `PLAYER` record.

Answer (score 2):

A set of columns comprising a foreign key in one table must refer to an equivalent set of columns in a table with either a Primary Key or Unique Key constraint.

You certainly can have 2 or more FKs in the same table that refer to the same PK or UK. This models a relationship where a child record is related to more than one parent record - e.g. a record representing a biological child might have a FK to the record for their father as well as for their mother.

Note that a unique index is not sufficient for this purpose; a unique constraint is required, otherwise you will get "ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list".